# How to print size of ICMP packet?

Tags: c, pcap

I use pcap to capture ICMP packets. In "main" function I set filter "char filter_exp[] = "icmp";", compile it and use "pcap_loop(handle, num_packets, got_packet, NULL);" to capture ICMP packets.

In function got_packet program detects ICMP, but I can't understand how to get and print size of ICMP packet.

I tried to use somthing like this:

```
case IPPROTO_ICMP:
            printf("   Protocol: ICMP\n");
            tcp = (struct sniff_tcp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);
            size_tcp = TH_OFF(tcp)*4;
            printf("~~~~ %u ~~~~", size_tcp);
            return;
```

but sometimes it prints "28", "36", or "0". I don't understand how ICMP packet size can be equal to zero. It seems like something wrong.

Can you help me write code, that print ICMP packet size?

Full code:

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

/* default snap length (maximum bytes per packet to capture) */
#define SNAP_LEN 1518

/* ethernet headers are always exactly 14 bytes [1] */
#define SIZE_ETHERNET 14

/* Ethernet addresses are 6 bytes */
#define ETHER_ADDR_LEN  6

/* Ethernet header */
struct sniff_ethernet {
        u_char  ether_dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    /* destination host address */
        u_char  ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    /* source host address */
        u_short ether_type;                     /* IP? ARP? RARP? etc */
};

/* IP header */
struct sniff_ip {
        u_char  ip_vhl;                 /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
        u_char  ip_tos;                 /* type of service */
        u_short ip_len;                 /* total length */
        u_short ip_id;                  /* identification */
        u_short ip_off;                 /* fragment offset field */
        #define IP_RF 0x8000            /* reserved fragment flag */
        #define IP_DF 0x4000            /* dont fragment flag */
        #define IP_MF 0x2000            /* more fragments flag */
        #define IP_OFFMASK 0x1fff       /* mask for fragmenting bits */
        u_char  ip_ttl;                 /* time to live */
        u_char  ip_p;                   /* protocol */
        u_short ip_sum;                 /* checksum */
        struct  in_addr ip_src,ip_dst;  /* source and dest address */
};
#define IP_HL(ip)               (((ip)->ip_vhl) & 0x0f)
#define IP_V(ip)                (((ip)->ip_vhl) >> 4)

/* TCP header */
typedef u_int tcp_seq;

struct sniff_tcp {
        u_short th_sport;               /* source port */
        u_short th_dport;               /* destination port */
        tcp_seq th_seq;                 /* sequence number */
        tcp_seq th_ack;                 /* acknowledgement number */
        u_char  th_offx2;               /* data offset, rsvd */
#define TH_OFF(th)      (((th)->th_offx2 & 0xf0) >> 4)
        u_char  th_flags;
        #define TH_FIN  0x01
        #define TH_SYN  0x02
        #define TH_RST  0x04
        #define TH_PUSH 0x08
        #define TH_ACK  0x10
        #define TH_URG  0x20
        #define TH_ECE  0x40
        #define TH_CWR  0x80
        #define TH_FLAGS        (TH_FIN|TH_SYN|TH_RST|TH_ACK|TH_URG|TH_ECE|TH_CWR)
        u_short th_win;                 /* window */
        u_short th_sum;                 /* checksum */
        u_short th_urp;                 /* urgent pointer */
};

void
got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet);

/*
 * dissect/print packet
 */
void
got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{

    static int count = 1;                   /* packet counter */

    /* declare pointers to packet headers */
    const struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet;  /* The ethernet header [1] */
    const struct sniff_ip *ip;              /* The IP header */
    const struct sniff_tcp *tcp;            /* The TCP header */
    const char *payload;                    /* Packet payload */

    int size_ip;
    int size_tcp;
    int size_payload;

    printf("\nPacket number %d:\n", count);
    count++;

    /* define ethernet header */
    ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);

    /* define/compute ip header offset */
    ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
    size_ip = IP_HL(ip)*4;
    if (size_ip < 20) {
        printf("   * Invalid IP header length: %u bytes\n", size_ip);
        return;
    }

    /* print source and destination IP addresses */
    printf("       From: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
    printf("         To: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst));

    /* determine protocol */    
    switch(ip->ip_p) {
        case IPPROTO_TCP:
            printf("   Protocol: TCP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_UDP:
            printf("   Protocol: UDP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_ICMP:
            printf("   Protocol: ICMP\n");
            tcp = (struct sniff_tcp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);
            size_tcp = TH_OFF(tcp)*4;
            printf("~~~~ %u ~~~~", size_tcp);
            return;
        case IPPROTO_IP:
            printf("   Protocol: IP\n");
            return;
        default:
            printf("   Protocol: unknown\n");
            return;
    }

return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char *dev = NULL;           /* capture device name */
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];      /* error buffer */
    pcap_t *handle;             /* packet capture handle */

    char filter_exp[] = "icmp";     /* filter expression [3] */
    struct bpf_program fp;          /* compiled filter program (expression) */
    bpf_u_int32 mask;           /* subnet mask */
    bpf_u_int32 net;            /* ip */
    int num_packets = 3;            /* number of packets to capture */

    /* check for capture device name on command-line */
    if (argc == 2) {
        dev = argv[1];
    }
    else if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: unrecognized command-line options\n\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        /* find a capture device if not specified on command-line */
        dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
        if (dev == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n",
                errbuf);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* get network number and mask associated with capture device */
    if (pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get netmask for device %s: %s\n",
            dev, errbuf);
        net = 0;
        mask = 0;
    }

    /* print capture info */
    printf("Device: %s\n", dev);
    printf("Number of packets: %d\n", num_packets);
    printf("Filter expression: %s\n", filter_exp);

    /* open capture device */
    handle = pcap_open_live(dev, SNAP_LEN, 1, 1000, errbuf);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* make sure we're capturing on an Ethernet device [2] */
    if (pcap_datalink(handle) != DLT_EN10MB) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s is not an Ethernet\n", dev);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* compile the filter expression */
    if (pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, net) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't parse filter %s: %s\n",
            filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* apply the compiled filter */
    if (pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't install filter %s: %s\n",
            filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* now we can set our callback function */
    pcap_loop(handle, num_packets, got_packet, NULL);

    /* cleanup */
    pcap_freecode(&fp);
    pcap_close(handle);

    printf("\nCapture complete.\n");

return 0;
}
```

Now I try this code and it prints "~~~ 98 ~~~". Is this code valid, or not?

```
void
got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{
...
...
/* determine protocol */    
    switch(ip->ip_p) {
        case IPPROTO_TCP:
            printf("   Protocol: TCP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_UDP:
            printf("   Protocol: UDP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_ICMP:
            printf("   Protocol: ICMP\n");
            //tcp = (struct sniff_tcp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);
            //size_tcp = TH_OFF(tcp)*4;
            printf("~~~~ %u ~~~~", header->len);
            return;
...
```

No, it isn't correct. I launched tcpdump, and it prints "length 64".

Comment: There are different types of ICMP packets, their length depends on the type.  [Look here](https://erg.abdn.ac.uk/useRS/gorry/couRSe/inet-pages/icmp-code.html) to get the gist.  Tcpdump is unlikely to include the IP header size.

Comment: @HansPassant but is it right, what I've done, or it isn't? My task looks like "Sort ICMP packets by their size".

Comment: It doesn't look wrong.  There are lots of utilities that use pcap and present a good view, best way to be sure.  Google "pcap viewer" to find them.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you.